# Drag and drop doesn't work with iFrame using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe, drag-and-drop

I've been implementing drag and drop using Vue.js

For the test, whenever a file is dragged and drroped in to dropzone, the browser says 'hello' alert.

But when I add `iFrame` to the template in the `VueCLI` project, it doesn't work. In other words, when a file is dragged and dropped into `dropzone`(red area), the browser opens it in a new tab instead of alert `hello`.

Something weird thing is that it works in `codepen.io`

https://codepen.io/primedev22/pen/yLJeaGN.

[image]

My project code snippet.

**Component**

```js
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div
      class="dropzone"
      @drop.prevent="doSomething()"
      @dragover.prevent
      @dragenter.prevent
      @dragleave.prevent
    ></div>
    <iframe
      src="https://vault.netvoyage.com/neWeb2/home"
      class="frame"
    ></iframe>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  methods: {
    doSomething() {
      alert('Hello!');
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.dropzone {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.frame {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
</style>
```

Why this weird stuff happen?

Comment: seeing as you can only show what works, you'll need to explain in what way *it doesn't work* ... do you get errors in the browser developer tools console? does your computer explode? ... *doesn't work* is not enough info when you can't demonstrate it not working

Comment: @Jaromanda X, Assume file is dragged and dropped into the `dropzone`, in case of `VueCLI`, it opens the file while `codepen.io` alerts `hello`

Comment: yes, I see it alerts hello ... perhaps the code you haven't shown is wrong ... i.e. where it "opens the file" - that's the bit you're probably doing wrong, and haven't shown

Comment: They use the same code base.

Comment: except the code you haven't shown "doesn't work" - so

Comment: @Jaromanda X, There is no code except the code I have shown.

Comment: sorry, I'm a bit thick today, I misunderstood what you meant by "it opens the file", I see now in the gif :p - I thought **your code** was trying to "open the file" on local, i.e. you had different code on local ... the only difference then is http vs https ... maybe

Comment: A wild guess: in the one that's not working `.frame` has a set `position` other than `static`, whereas in the example (where it works, it's not set, therefore `static`). If I'm correct, the fix is to either set `position: static` on `.frame` or to give `.dropzone` a higher `z-index` than `.frame`s (most likely `1` will sufice). You're basically dropping the file in the `iframe`, not on the `.dropzone`.

Comment: Did anyone manage this to work? I am facing a big problem with this